# Mupdf compile with only pdf support

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, mupdf, pdf-viewer

I was working on a lightweight pdf viewer, and I wanted the size to be of the range of 5 MBs,
I am using mupdf , but the compiled .so file itself is around 16.6 MBs,

Is there a way to compile mupdf with only pdf support and not the others like xps, images, etc.
Like this app on google play, the file of .so file is just 3 MBs
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.geraldthaler.octopuspdf,

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured, It was because of the font packs,
compiling without extra font packs generates very small .so's

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant:
There is a configuration file In MuPDF source that lets you throw out features **before** you generate the library, called config.h located in directory mupdf/include/fitz.
By setting the appropriate #define statements, XPS, EPUB, etc. can be opted out. The biggest space saver is however opting out certain fonts. In essence you can restrict your library to PDF's Base-14 (Helvetica, Times-Roman, Courier, Symbol and ZapfDingbats) fonts. You also can opt out support for various image format support.
Taking all that together should bring you down well below 5 MB.